# value range and meaning for Mirth CONTENT_TYPE column

Tags: mirth

The Mirth tables with prefix `D_MC` (theese are each channel's content tables) have a column named `CONTENT_TYPE`. These columns have number/integer values.

How can I find out what each of these values in these columns mean?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this link: http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/fisheye/

**Code:**

```
public enum ContentType {

       RAW(1), PROCESSED_RAW(2), TRANSFORMED(3), ENCODED(4), SENT(5), RESPONSE(6), RESPONSE_TRANSFORMED(
               7), PROCESSED_RESPONSE(8), CONNECTOR_MAP(9), CHANNEL_MAP(10), RESPONSE_MAP(11), PROCESSING_ERROR(
               12), POSTPROCESSOR_ERROR(13), RESPONSE_ERROR(14), SOURCE_MAP(15);}
```